# storing the values of select dropdowns in localstorage within a loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, local-storage

I am currently working on storing a bunch of form values using localStorage. Unfortunately, we are using  dropdown input fields, and when I serialize the array with this: $("#formID").serializeArray(); it serializes the text inputs but not the select dropdowns.

I have therefore had to store the values using a click event handler like so:

```
$("#k12_msa_1").click(function() { localStorage.setItem("k12", "YES"); });
$("#k12_msa_2").click(function() { localStorage.setItem("k12", "NO"); });
if (localStorage.getItem("k12") == "YES") { $("#k12_titletext").text("YES"); }
if (localStorage.getItem("k12") == "NO") { $("#k12_titletext").text("NO"); }
```

The 1 immediately after the k is the question number. Since I will end up having 49 questions, I don't want to have four lines of code for each question. I want to use a loop. However, I have had a difficult time constructing that loop. I was thinking something like this:

```
var yes = function () {
localStorage.setItem("k" + i + 2, "YES");
}
var no = function () {
localStorage.setItem("k" + i + 2, "NO");
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 49; i++) {
$("#k" + i + "2_msa_1").on('click', yes() );
$("#k" + i + "2_msa_1").on('click', no() );
if (localStorage.getItem("k" + i + 2) == "YES") { $("#k" + i + "2_titletext").text("YES"); }
if (localStorage.getItem("k" + i + 2) == "NO") { $("#k" + i + "2_titletext").text("NO"); }
}
});
```

But, it's not working. I'm no good at jquery, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle with a workable example?

Comment: @DanJ. Thank you for your quick response! I have put together a partial replica of my code, which is linked below. As you can see, when you refresh the page, anything you typed in the text input fields will be saved. The YES/NO Dropdown doesn't, however. I am not worried about the Rating dropdown, because I think if I figure out the YES/NO, the other will follow the same structure, roughly. Anyway, here is the fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Kzn7U/5/). Lines 1-25 work pretty well. My jquery doesn't work, however, from line 27-41. Lines 42 onward is irrelevant, I think.